# How can I perform a function onto the value of each instance of a property in a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, recursion

I've got an object like this. It'll continue in this format with more and more children blocks but this snippet gives an idea. I'm trying to replace the value of data, throughout this entire object with an NLP parsed version.

```json
{
"date": "next friday"
"more text": "someVariable"
"children": [{
    "date": "today"
    "more text": "someVariable"
    "children": [{
        "date": "yesterday"
        "more text": "someVariable"
        "children": []}, 
        {"date": "yesterday"
        "more text": "someVariable"
        "children": []}] 
}
}
```

What I'd like to do is to run a text replace function onto *only* the values of "date" throughout the entire array and return a mutated object where everything remains the same except for the value of "date" whenever the find and replcae operation is successful.

I'm essentially running NLP on the value of item "date"

I've attempted a recursive function but can't figure out how to maintain the original structure.

```js
async function parseChildren(obj, child = true){
    for (var k in obj)
    {if (obj[k] !== null){
        // console.log(obj(k))
        if (k == "date"){
            console.log(obj[k])
            console.log(parseDates(obj[k]))
        }
        if (k == "children"){
            parseChildren(obj[k], false)
        }
        else if (child == false) {
        parseChildren(obj[k])
        }
        
    }
}
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Why is `parseChildren()` marked as `async`?

Comment: _"and return a mutated object"_ - Why return something? Why not just store the new value in the `date` property? Which would also "solve" -> _"how to maintain the original structure"_

Comment: _"I've attempted a recursive function..."_ - Okay. But where's the actual relevant part (_"and return a mutated object where everything remains the same except for the value of "date" whenever the find and replcae operation is successful."_)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```js
const test = {
    "date": "next friday",
    "more text": "someVariable",
    "children": [{
        "date": "today",
        "more text": "someVariable",
        "children": [{
            "date": "yesterday",
            "more text": "someVariable",
            "children": []}, 
            {"date": "yesterday",
            "more text": "someVariable",
            "children": []}] 
    }]
    }

function mutateDates(obj){
    if (obj.date) {
        obj.date = 'mutation_here_we_it_is'
    }

    obj.children.map(mutateDates)
}

mutateDates(test)
```

This will result into:

```
{
    "date": "mutation_here_we_it_is",
    "more text": "someVariable",
    "children": [{
        "date": "mutation_here_we_it_is",
        "more text": "someVariable",
        "children": [{
            "date": "mutation_here_we_it_is",
            "more text": "someVariable",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "date": "mutation_here_we_it_is",
            "more text": "someVariable",
            "children": []
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was lookign for! Thank you! Could you perhaps walk me through the what exactly you did? Specifically this line, `    obj.children.map(mutateDates)
`? Thank you so mcuh!